# ggradar: how to increase space for long axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggradar

I want to create a radar chart with ggradar package. The problem is that I have long labels and they are clipped (as shown in the figure below inside two red rectangles).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggradar)

df <- structure(list(date = c("2022-1-31", "2022-2-28"), 
                     Item_A_Long = c(50.1, 50.2), 
                     Item_B_Very_Very_Long = c(48.4, 49), 
                     Another_Item_C_very_long_label = c(47.2, 48.6)),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
df

df %>% 
  mutate(across(contains('Item'), ~ (.x - 45) / 10)) %>%
  ggradar(values.radar = c('45', '50', '55'),
          legend.position = 'bottom') +
  theme(
        axis.text = element_text(hjust=0.5, vjust = 1)
        # margin = margin(0, 0, 2, 0, 'cm')
        )
```

Out:

[image]

I thought I could create more space between label and plot by adding `axis.text = element_text(hjust=0.5, vjust = 1)` or `plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 2, 0, 'cm')`, but its not working.

Any ideas how to increase the label space are welcome (apart from making the font smaller).

**Reference:**

[Increase space for long axis labels in radar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67334137/increase-space-for-long-axis-labels-in-radar-chart)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could increase the `plot.margin` and add `coord_cartesian(clip = "off")`. However, this distorts the dimensions of your radar chart. I played around with the plot pane to account for that. However, I'm sure there are cleverer solutions to your problem.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(contains('Item'), ~ (.x - 45) / 10)) %>%
  ggradar(values.radar = c('45', '50', '55'),
          legend.position = 'bottom') +
  theme(
    axis.text = element_text(hjust=0.5, vjust = 1),
    plot.margin = margin(0, 5, 0, 5, 'cm')) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]